# JUnit4 Categories results are different between @SuiteClasses vs. TestSuite

Tags: java, junit4

I am trying to run a JUnit4 test using categories against an AllTests suite of tests. In example 1 running Suite3 works and example 2 running Suite2 produces the following exception.

```
java.lang.Exception: Category annotations on Parameterized classes
are not supported on individual methods.
```

I need to generate the TestSuite as the test is executed.

Any suggestions for how to correct the problem?
Thanks

example 1

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(SlowTest.class)
@SuiteClasses(AllTests3.class)
public class Suite3 {
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
           MathUtilTest.class, MathUtil2Test.class
})
public class AllTests3 {
}
```

example 2

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(SlowTest.class)
@SuiteClasses(AllTests2.class)
public class Suite2 {
}

public final class AllTests2 {
    public static TestSuite suite() {
        final TestSuite result = new TestSuite();
        result.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(MathUtilTest.class));
        result.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(MathUtil2Test.class));
        return result;
    }

    private AllTests2() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various related bugs in the latest stable version of JUnit 4 (4.12):

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1203

Somebody committed a fix for the unreleased 4.13-SNAPSHOT version, which you can build and check out yourself by cloning their GitHub repo over at https://github.com/junit-team/junit4

However, I ran a couple of tests myself and have to conclude that the @Category annotation does work when used on your MathUtilTest class, but only if the class is annotated, the annotation is ignored when used on individual test methods.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to annotate methods. Will look into building the 4.13 jar.